# start with 0 before other numeric value on oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE "AREA" (
  "COMPANY_CODE" NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 020,
  "AREA_CODE"    VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL DISABLE,
  "AREA_NAME"    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  "LOCATION"     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT "AREA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("AREA_CODE"));
```

Here Area_code is varchar2 and size is 5. 
As example
Now I have to enter 00015, then its output is 00015.
When I entry only 15, it comes out only 15.

Have any trigger or function (as like uppercase trigger) that output will 00015 by entry only 15. 
As like (14 = 00014, 350 = 00350), my man automatically '0' will fill up the blank size.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a function [LPAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm#OLADM593)

```
LPAD(area_code, 5, '0');
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/23621)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made it . create or replace TRIGGER TR_AREA_CODE_LPAD
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF AREA_CODE
  ON AREA 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.AREA_CODE := LPAD(:new.AREA_CODE,5,'0');
END;